# os.scandir gives [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, windows, scandir

I have a (large) set of XML files that I want to search for a set of strings all being present within - I am trying to use the following Python code to do this:

```
import collections

thestrings = []
with open('Strings.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    text = line.strip()
    thestrings.append(text)

print('Searching for:')
print(thestrings)
print('Results:')

try:
  from os import scandir
except ImportError:
  from scandir import scandir

def scantree(path):
  """Recursively yield DirEntry objects for given directory."""
  for entry in scandir(path):
    if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False) and (not entry.name.startswith('.')):
      yield from scantree(entry.path)
    else:
      yield entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for entry in scantree('//path/to/folder'):
    if ('.xml' in entry.name) and ('.zip' not in entry.name):
      with open(entry.path) as f:
        data = f.readline()
        if (thestrings[0] in data):
          print('')
          print('****** Schema found in: ', entry.name)
          print('')
          data = f.read()
          if (thestrings[1] in data) and (thestrings[2] in data) and (thestrings[3] in data):
            print('Hit at:', entry.path)

  print("Done!")
```

Where Strings.txt is a file with the strings I am interested to find, and the first line is the schema URI.

This seems to run OK at first, but after some seconds gives me a:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: //some/path
```

Which is confusing me, since the path is being built during runtime?

Note, if I instrument the code as follows:

```
with open(entry.path) as f:
  data = f.readline()
  if (thestrings[0] in data):
```

To become:

```
with open(entry.path) as f:
  print(entry.name)
  data = f.readline()
  if (thestrings[0] in data):
```

Then I see a number of potential files being found before the error occurs.

Comment: Maybe the path beginning with double slash `//some/path` is interpreted as a remote SMB path, as in `\\server\shared`? And then you do not have access to a server named `path` or `some`.

Comment: A side note: your `scantree` function is re-inventing `os.walk`.

Comment: @rodrigo, as shown it is a UNC path, but the likely error in that case is `ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME` (67). Getting `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3) implies either a local device name doesn't exist (e.g. listing an unmapped drive letter) or a path component wasn't found -- except if the final component isn't found the error is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2).

Comment: @rodigro, eryksun is correct, I am using a UNC path

Comment: @Błotosmętek yes, I guess it does!  I will try to rewrite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that my script is finding some very long UNC path names, too long for Windows it seems, so I am now also checking the path length before attempting to open the file, as follows:

```
if name.endswith('.xml'):
  fullpath = os.path.join(root, name)
  if (len(fullpath) > 255): ##Too long for Windows!
    print('File-extension-based candidate: ', fullpath)
  else:
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
      with open(fullpath) as f:
        data = f.readline()
        if (thestrings[0] in data):
          print('Schema-based candidate: ', fullpath)
```

Note, I also decided to check if the file really is a file, and I altered my code to use os.walk, as suggested above.  Along with simplifying the check for a .xml file-extension by using .endswith()

Everything now seems to work OK...